# proper use of call_user_func_array

Tags: php, callback, smarty, argument-passing, lithium

I'm attempting to extend Lithium PHP with smarty, everything is working except my smarty plugin to allow access to lithium helpers.

My smarty function is meant to be a "catchall" for lithium helpers. The part I'm struggling with is dynamically adding the helpers parameters to my callback.

**Simplified Code**

```
$params = array('Google', 'http://www.google.com');

$helper = function($args){  
    return $this->html->link($args);
};

return call_user_func_array($helper, $params);
```

This results with `<a href="/Google">Google</a>`

Some further testing showed that the above only passed the first item in the $params array to the callback... strange. So I wrapped it in its own array. Take that, thing I cant explain!

```
return call_user_func_array($helper, array($params));
```

This produces a lithium error which I wont get into, however it appears that the helper is being passed an array, not translated arguments from the array as individual parameters.

**Error snippet**
'No parameter match found for URL `( 0 => 'Google', 1 => 'http://www.google.com', 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index')`.

So I gather that I'm missusing the call_user_func_array method.

I'm not sold on this being the only solution to achieve my end, if you can think of a better way to dynamically pass a function any number of arguments at any time I would be greatful.

> **Please note**: $this->`html`->`link` is a simplified method to explain my issue, the `html` and `link` parts of that object will actually dynamically changed, hence the requirement for completely dynamic function arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$helper` is declared with only one argument and only one is transfered to `$this->html->link`.

Why not use `call_user_func_array(array($this->html, 'link'), array($params));` directly?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do

```
return $helper($params);
```

No need for `call_user_func_array()` in my opinion.
Or please clarify why you want this, because for me this works.

Comment: The problem is $this->html->link needs to be passed something like this $this->html->link('Google', 'http://www.google.com'), not $this->html->link(array('Google', 'http://www.google.com')), so just passing in $params wont suffice.

Comment: Okay now I understood :) Then my answer became obsolete.

Comment: Thanks anyway, @kirlloid's answer got me where I needed to go